# Enforce DataFrame types and allow NaN

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to initialize an empty pandas DataFrame with certain data types for the columns and then append to the DataFrame some rows which may not contain all the columns, but the content of a column must be the one declared when the DataFrame.
Is there a way to do this?

```
record_list = [
                   { 'lastname'    : 'Ford',
          'firstname'  : 'Ana',
          'agreed'     : 0
                   },
                   { 'lastname'    : 'Snow',
          'agreed'     : 'a'
                    }
                    ]
    df = pd.DataFrame({
    'lastname'    : np.array([], dtype=np.object),
        'firstname'   : np.array([], dtype=np.object),                       
            'agreed'      : np.array([], dtype=np.int64)
                    })

for record in record_list:
    df = df.append([record], ignore_index=True)
```

The above should fail because 'agreed' is string, not int, but if it was int, then a NaN should be put in the dataframe for the second record, even if the type is str.
I also tried columns and dtype separately, but did not work. Please help!

Comment: What exactly is your workflow and what kind of error handling do you need? How large is the data and how often will you run this? I am not aware of a way to get pandas to enforce data types. Can you run this data entry process outside of pandas? In SQL or with an ETL tool?

Comment: Also look into: http://www.tdda.info/constraint-discovery-and-verification-for-pandas-dataframes which, however, tests ex-post, not while data is being added

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear properly what you finally want. But I am explaining what I have understood. Think pandas as a traditional database. You can not put str and int at the same column. But by default in pandas if there is `NaN` in a column with data type int it will always show the data as decimal Ex. `0.0` It's better to first clean the data and insert in to a new list and then read directly to a Dataframe.

```
new_data = []
for item in record_list:
    agrd = item.get("agreed", None)
    if isinstance(agrd, int):
        new_data.append(item)
    else:
        item["agreed"] = None
        new_data.append(item)

df = pd.DataFrame(new_data)
```

Result:

```
   agreed firstname lastname
0     0.0       Ana     Ford
1     NaN       NaN     Snow
```

Because there is NaN pandas will always show decimal instead of int. So you can replace the NaN by `df.<columnname>.fillna(value=-1)` and then convert the column using `df["columnname"] = df.columnname.astype(int)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.to_numeric()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) like below for validation once the data is loaded and treat them you like:

```
df=df.append(record_list)
df.agreed=np.where(pd.to_numeric(df.agreed,errors='coerce').isna(),np.nan,df.agreed)
print(df)

  lastname firstname agreed
0     Ford       Ana      0
1     Snow       NaN    NaN
```